# How can i specify to python cffi , to add my import modules into the generated DLL?

Tags: python, dll, python-cffi, modulenotfounderror, cffi

i have a simple Python code to generate a Dll Using CFFI :

```
import cffi 
 ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()

ffibuilder.embedding_api("""
  int Predict();
""")

ffibuilder.set_source("landmark_Library", "")



ffibuilder.embedding_init_code("""
from landmark_Library import ffi
import argparse
from parse_config import ConfigParser
import deepmvlm
from utils3d import Utils3D
@ffi.def_extern()
def Predict():
    return 2
""")

ffibuilder.compile(target="landmark_Library.*", verbose=True)
```

i got this error when calling the dll function :
if i add the directory with sys.path.insert(0, "."), it will only work only in my computer , if i change computer the dll will stop working and i get this error.

[image: the dll function is called but he can't find the imports]

Comment: Did you succeeded with dependencies embeding in dll ?

Answer (score 0):

The error should be self-descriptive: you are doing `from parse_config import ...` but there is no module `parse_config` found.

If you know where the module really is (e.g. in some `parse_config.py` file or `parse_config\\__init__.py` file), then make sure that location is in `sys.path`.  The current value of `sys.path` is printed as part of the error message.  You can check if it is indeed missing, and if so, you can add it.  In particular, it seems that the current directory `.` is not in `sys.path` in your case, so maybe you need to add that (write `sys.path.insert(0, ".")` on a line before `from parse_config import ...`).  Replace `"."` with the real path if it is somewhere else.

Comment: my problem is that i add the directory with sys.path.insert(0, "."), it will only work only in my computer , if i change computer the dll will stop working  :(  i need to compile the Module inside my dll or create dll for each module . i don't know how to compile the modules to be used by my dll .

Comment: Your problem might not have a good solution that works in all cases.  You need somehow to make sure there is a Python interpreter and all necessary Python files on the target machine.  There are various ways to do that, like for example packing a directory inside your application with all of them (and then you say ``sys.path.insert(0, "my_directory")``).

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion , i will try to add path of the folder that contains all necessary Modules and add it automatically to to home path on every machine that run my program.